# who can help me with this error of this program? Thank you very much. Sorry if my english is not good

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am a beginner of java and here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CheckPassword {
    public static void PasswordValidator(String password) {
        int n = password.length();
        boolean hasDigit = false, specialChar = false, hasLetter = false;
        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList('!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '+'));
        for (char i : password.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(i))
                hasLetter = true;
            if (Character.isDigit(i))
                hasDigit = true;
            if (set.contains(i))
                specialChar = true;
        }
        int onlydigit = 0;
        int onlyletter = 0;
        if (n >= 1) {
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                char x = password.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isDigit(x)) {
                    onlydigit++;
                }
                if (Character.isLetter(x)) {
                    onlyletter++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Your password " + '"' + password + '"' + " is ");
        if (n < 8) {
            if (n == onlydigit) {
                System.out.println("very weak");
            } else {
                System.out.println("weak");
            }
        } else {
            if ((hasDigit == true) && (hasLetter == true)) {
                if ((onlydigit + onlyletter) == n) {
                    System.out.println("strong");
                } else {
                    if (specialChar == true) {
                        System.out.println("very strong");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD: ");
        String password = sc.nextLine();
        PasswordValidator(password);
    }
}
```

Visual Studio Code give me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
> i cannot be resolved to a variable
> i cannot be resolved to a variable
> i cannot be resolved to a variable
> i cannot be resolved to a variable
>
> at CheckPassword.PasswordValidator(CheckPassword.java:21)
> at CheckPassword.main(CheckPassword.java:56)

who can help me with this error?

Comment: The `i` in the second for loop needs to be declared as a new `int`: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {`

Comment: Please accept one of the answers if it correctly solves your problem. You've had two days to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare i as an "int" variable. On line 20, you forgot to write int before you wrote (i = 0; i < n; i++). I fixed that line in your code below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CheckPassword {
    public static void PasswordValidator(String password) {
        int n = password.length();
        boolean hasDigit = false, specialChar = false, hasLetter = false;
        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList('!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '+'));
        for (char i : password.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(i))
                hasLetter = true;
            if (Character.isDigit(i))
                hasDigit = true;
            if (set.contains(i))
                specialChar = true;
        }
        int onlydigit = 0;
        int onlyletter = 0;
        if (n >= 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                char x = password.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isDigit(x)) {
                    onlydigit++;
                }
                if (Character.isLetter(x)) {
                    onlyletter++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Your password " + '"' + password + '"' + " is ");
        if (n < 8) {
            if (n == onlydigit) {
                System.out.println("very weak");
            } else {
                System.out.println("weak");
            }
        } else {
            if ((hasDigit == true) && (hasLetter == true)) {
                if ((onlydigit + onlyletter) == n) {
                    System.out.println("strong");
                } else {
                    if (specialChar == true) {
                        System.out.println("very strong");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD: ");
        String password = sc.nextLine();
        PasswordValidator(password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 21 (for loop with `i`), you didn't declare the type. Fixing it with `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`. Should fix the issue.